# Incremental of input type="number"

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to allow user to increase number in `input type="number"` by 10 via clicking the up down arrow, at the same time also allowing the user to enter random numbers (e.g. 33) instead of just accepting numbers like 30, 40 only?

**Note**: this `input type="number"` cannot accept negative numbers, max value is 100.

Comment: have you tried something? Share your code.

Comment: I have tried what you did, and it doesn't work, as @dave said in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated with @Navnath Jadhav's suggestion.

You'll need a custom implementation for this.

The below adds an increment and deincrement button next to the input field and hides the default number arrows.

```js
let deincrement = document.getElementById("deincrement");
let increment = document.getElementById("increment");
let number = document.getElementById("number");

let step = 10;
let max = 100;
let min = 0;

number.oninput = () => {   

  number.value = number.value>max ? max : number.value<min ? min : number.value; 
  
}; 

increment.addEventListener("click", () => {
    
  if (parseInt(number.value) + step >= max) {
    number.value = max;
    return;
  }
    
  number.value = parseInt(number.value) + step;

})


deincrement.addEventListener("click", () => {
  
  if (parseInt(number.value) - step <= min) {
    number.value = min;
    return;
  }
    
  number.value = parseInt(number.value) - step;

})
```

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="deincrement">-</button>
<input type="number" value="33" id="number" min="0" max="100"/>
<button type="button" id="increment">+</button>
```

Comment: That's a good solution. But we can't restrict users manually adding negative numbers or numbers greater than 100. We can improve your answer by listening to input to do a check if the number is below 0 or above 100. Like `number.oninput = function(){
  number.value = number.value>100 ? 100 : number.value<0 ? 0 : number.value;
};
`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [min, max](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp) attribute along with [step](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_step.asp)

```html
<input type="number" step="10" min="0" max="100"/>
```

Comment: I think this only answers part of the question. If you enter the number 33 it'll round it to 40 when you increment it, not increment to 43

Comment: I tried this before, and it is as what @dave said